# Reference a workbook when running Excel VBA code within Outlook instead

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The code below works when it is run within the destination Excel workbook.

I want to run the macro from within Outlook.

When I try to add the path to the destination file, it says the subscript is out of range:

```vb
    Dim DestFile as Object 
    Set DestFile = Workbooks("T:\3-Lending Systems Analyst\Collections Master Workbook.xlsm")
```

Is it because it's on an external drive?
Do I need to activate the ExcelApp first and/or Open the Workbook?

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractDataFromOutlookEmail()
    
    ' Late binding. Outlook variables declared as Object.
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Object
    Dim OutlookFolder As Object
    Dim OutlookItem As Object
    Dim Attachment As Object
    
    Dim ExcelWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim ExcelWorksheet As Worksheet
    
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    
    Dim RangeToExtract As Range
    Dim RangeToCopy As Range
    
    ' Set the path where you want to save the extracted data
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp")
    
      ******' Set the range where you want to paste the extracted data
    Set DestFile = T:\3-Lending Systems Analyst\Collections Master Workbook TESTING.xlsm
    Set RangeToExtract = DestFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' Change to your desired range******
    
    ' Create a new Outlook application
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' Specify the Outlook folder where the email is located
    Set OutlookFolder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Projects").Folders("Collections").Folders("Daily Reports") ' Change to the appropriate folder
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Loop through the emails in the folder
    For Each OutlookItem In OutlookFolder.Items
    
        'Debug.Print OutlookItem.Subject
        
        If TypeName(OutlookItem) = "MailItem" Then
        
            ' Check if the email has the desired attachments
            If OutlookItem.Attachments.Count >= 1 Then
                
                ' Check if the attachments have specific titles
                Dim AttachmentTitles(1 To 3) As String
                AttachmentTitles(1) = "Queue Status - Collections.csv" ' Replace with the title of the first attachment
                AttachmentTitles(2) = "KPI Collections - Inbound.csv" ' Replace with the title of the second attachment
                AttachmentTitles(3) = "KPI Collections - Outbound.csv" ' Replace with the title of the third attachment
                
                Dim AttachmentCount As Long
                AttachmentCount = 0
                
                ' Loop through the attachments in the email
                For Each Attachment In OutlookItem.Attachments
                    If Attachment.Filename = AttachmentTitles(1) Then
                        
                        ' Save the attachment to the temporary location
                        Attachment.SaveAsFile TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(1)
                        
                        ' Open the saved Excel attachment
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(1))
                        
                        ' Copy the data from the Excel attachment
                        Set RangeToCopy = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:S12") ' Assuming data is in the first sheet
                        
                        RangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=RangeToExtract.Offset ' Offset to paste data in different columns
                        
                        ' Close the Excel attachment
                        ExcelWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                        
                        ' Clean up Excel objects
                        Set ExcelWorksheet = Nothing
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
                        
                        ' Increment the attachment count
                        AttachmentCount = AttachmentCount + 1
                        
                        ' Exit the loop if all three attachments are processed
                        If AttachmentCount >= 3 Then Exit For
                            
                    End If
                Next Attachment
                
                For Each Attachment In OutlookItem.Attachments
                
                    If Attachment.Filename = AttachmentTitles(2) Then
                        
                        ' Save the attachment to the temporary location
                        Attachment.SaveAsFile TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(2)
                        
                        ' Open the saved Excel attachment
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(2))
                        
                        ' Copy the data from the Excel attachment
                        Set RangeToCopy = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("H2:X12") ' Assuming data is in the first sheet
                        
                        RangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=RangeToExtract.Offset(, 19) ' Offset to paste data in different columns
                        
                        ' Close the Excel attachment
                        ExcelWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                        
                        ' Clean up Excel objects
                        Set ExcelWorksheet = Nothing
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
                        
                        ' Increment the attachment count
                        AttachmentCount = AttachmentCount + 1
                        
                        ' Exit the loop if all three attachments are processed
                        If AttachmentCount >= 3 Then Exit For
                            
                    End If
                Next Attachment
                
                For Each Attachment In OutlookItem.Attachments
                
                    If Attachment.Filename = AttachmentTitles(3) Then
                        
                        ' Save the attachment to the temporary location
                        Attachment.SaveAsFile TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(3)
                        
                        ' Open the saved Excel attachment
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(3))
                        
                        ' Copy the data from the Excel attachment
                        Set RangeToCopy = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("H2:X12") ' Assuming data is in the first sheet
                        
                        RangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=RangeToExtract.Offset(, 36) ' Offset to paste data in different columns
                        
                        ' Close the Excel attachment
                        ExcelWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                            
                        ' Clean up Excel objects
                        Set ExcelWorksheet = Nothing
                        Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
                         
                        ' Increment the attachment count
                        AttachmentCount = AttachmentCount + 1
                            
                        ' Exit the loop if all three attachments are processed
                        If AttachmentCount >= 3 Then Exit For
                            
                    End If
                Next Attachment
            End If
        End If
    Next OutlookItem
    
    ' Clean up Outlook objects
    Set OutlookItem = Nothing
    Set OutlookFolder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    
    ' Delete the temporary Excel files
    If Dir(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(1)) <> "" Then
        Kill TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(1)
    End If
    
    If Dir(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(2)) <> "" Then
        Kill TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(2)
    End If
        
    If Dir(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(3)) <> "" Then
        Kill TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(3)
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Close
    ExcelApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Recommend reading on Early/Late Binding

Comment: Edited the question to show where error occurs **Set the range...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When running in Excel VBA, Application intrinsic variable points to an instance of the `Excel.Application` object, and it is exposed in a way that makes all of its properties and methods global, i.e. you don't have to use `Application.Worksheets`, you can just use `Worksheets`.
2. When running inside Outlook VBA, `Application` points to an instance of the `Outlook.Application` objects.

You need to take the two points above into account. Off the top of my head, I might have missed something:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractDataFromOutlookEmail()
    
    ' Late binding. Outlook variables declared as Object.
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim ExcelApp As Object
    Dim ThisWorkbook As Object
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Object
    Dim OutlookFolder As Object
    Dim OutlookItem As Object
    Dim Attachment As Object
    
    Dim ExcelWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim ExcelWorksheet As Worksheet
    
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    
    Dim RangeToExtract As Range
    Dim RangeToCopy As Range
    
    ' Set the path where you want to save the extracted data
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp")

    'ThisWorkbook must be initialized explicitly
    set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    set ThisWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\some.worksheet.xlsx") 
    
    ' Set the range where you want to paste the extracted data
    
    ' **** ThisWorkbook is used - code must be in Excel ****
    Set RangeToExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' Change to your desired range
    
    ' Create a new Outlook application
    Set OutlookApp = Application 'Application points to Outlook.Application in Outlook VBA
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' Specify the Outlook folder where the email is located
    Set OutlookFolder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Projects").Folders("Collections").Folders("Daily Reports") ' Change to the appropriate folder
    
    ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Loop through the emails in the folder
    For Each OutlookItem In OutlookFolder.Items
    
        'Debug.Print OutlookItem.Subject
        
        If TypeName(OutlookItem) = "MailItem" Then
        
            ' Check if the email has the desired attachments
            
            If OutlookItem.Attachments.Count >= 1 Then
                
                ' Check if the attachments have specific titles
                Dim AttachmentTitles(1 To 3) As String
                AttachmentTitles(1) = "Queue Status - Collections.csv" ' Replace with the title of the first attachment
                AttachmentTitles(2) = "KPI Collections - Inbound.csv" ' Replace with the title of the second attachment
                AttachmentTitles(3) = "KPI Collections - Outbound.csv" ' Replace with the title of the third attachment
                
                Dim AttachmentCount As Long
                AttachmentCount = 0
                
                ' Loop through the attachments in the email
                
                
                For Each Attachment In OutlookItem.Attachments
                    
                    
                        
                        If Attachment.Filename = AttachmentTitles(1) Then
                            
                            ' Save the attachment to the temporary location
                            Attachment.SaveAsFile TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(1)
                            
                            ' Open the saved Excel attachment
                            Set ExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(1))
                            
                            ' Copy the data from the Excel attachment
                            Set RangeToCopy = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:S12") ' Assuming data is in the first sheet
                            
                            RangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=RangeToExtract.Offset ' Offset to paste data in different columns
                            
                            ' Close the Excel attachment
                            ExcelWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                            
                            ' Clean up Excel objects
                            Set ExcelWorksheet = Nothing
                            Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
                            
                            ' Increment the attachment count
                            AttachmentCount = AttachmentCount + 1
                            
                            ' Exit the loop if all three attachments are processed
                            If AttachmentCount >= 3 Then Exit For
                            
                        End If
                        
                    
                    
                Next Attachment
                
                For Each Attachment In OutlookItem.Attachments
                
                        If Attachment.Filename = AttachmentTitles(2) Then
                            
                            ' Save the attachment to the temporary location
                            Attachment.SaveAsFile TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(2)
                            
                            ' Open the saved Excel attachment
                            Set ExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(2))
                            
                            ' Copy the data from the Excel attachment
                            Set RangeToCopy = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("H2:X12") ' Assuming data is in the first sheet
                            
                            RangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=RangeToExtract.Offset(, 19) ' Offset to paste data in different columns
                            
                            ' Close the Excel attachment
                            ExcelWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                            
                            ' Clean up Excel objects
                            Set ExcelWorksheet = Nothing
                            Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
                            
                            ' Increment the attachment count
                            AttachmentCount = AttachmentCount + 1
                            
                            ' Exit the loop if all three attachments are processed
                            If AttachmentCount >= 3 Then Exit For
                            
                        End If
                        
                    
                    
                Next Attachment
                
                For Each Attachment In OutlookItem.Attachments
                
                        If Attachment.Filename = AttachmentTitles(3) Then
                            
                            ' Save the attachment to the temporary location
                            Attachment.SaveAsFile TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(3)
                            
                            ' Open the saved Excel attachment
                            Set ExcelWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(3))
                            
                            ' Copy the data from the Excel attachment
                            Set RangeToCopy = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("H2:X12") ' Assuming data is in the first sheet
                            
                            RangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=RangeToExtract.Offset(, 36) ' Offset to paste data in different columns
                            
                            ' Close the Excel attachment
                            ExcelWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                            
                            ' Clean up Excel objects
                            Set ExcelWorksheet = Nothing
                            Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
                            
                            ' Increment the attachment count
                            AttachmentCount = AttachmentCount + 1
                            
                            ' Exit the loop if all three attachments are processed
                            If AttachmentCount >= 3 Then Exit For
                            
                        End If
                        
                    
                    
                Next Attachment
                
            End If
        
        End If
        
    Next OutlookItem
    
    ' Clean up Outlook objects
    Set OutlookItem = Nothing
    Set OutlookFolder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    
    ' Delete the temporary Excel files
    
        If Dir(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(1)) <> "" Then
            Kill TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(1)
        End If
        
        If Dir(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(2)) <> "" Then
            Kill TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(2)
        End If
        
        If Dir(TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(3)) <> "" Then
            Kill TempFilePath & AttachmentTitles(3)
        End If
    
    ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This ran without any errors, but it seems to be stuck in a loop.  Now the subject workbook is read-only saying it's locked for editing and I can't get it to unlock.  I tried adding:
 ThisWorkbook.Save
    
    ThisWorkbook.Close
    
    ExcelApp.Quit

But I think I need to get the loop unstuck first.  Any thoughts?  Thank you so much for your help!!  On a separate issue when this happened I needed to add late binding to the code, but I'm not sure how that works with subfolders...

Comment: Hard to say without actually debugging the code and stepping one line at a time... Did you restart Outlook to make sure it does not hold a reference to your worksheet? Did you check in the Task Manager (processes tab) that multiple excel.exe processes are running?

Comment: Wow so the code worked!!! But, it's saving a new copy of the results in my local C: Drive instead of saving the results/updating within the original file that is located in my T: Drive.  And then it's locking up the T: Drive subject file to read-only.  No additional Outlook or Excel apps are running, I checked.  So I need it to ultimately overwrite the original file in the original location?  I updated the original question showing how I put the .save and .close and .quit at the end

Comment: Which line is saving in the wrong location?

Comment: It's working!!!!  My apologies I had checked open apps but I didn't look at open Processes and there was 6 excel processes that was hanging everything up and causing the errors.  I closed them all out and have tested it 3 separate times with success!!! Thank you so much.  Now I just have to figure out how to run this macro automatically every day at a certain time in Outlook and then sweep the 3 emails to a specific folder once extracted.  Thank you thank you

Comment: If the answer answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!